# What is this old manual tool for?

Tags: hand-tools

I just found this in a pile of old tools, more or less related to plumbing.

[image]

The edges are sharp. The ridges do not have the same size on both sides.

Does anyone know what this is and what it is for?

Comment: looks likes it would be good for mudding lathes/flooring with grooves to hold tile. is there grout residue?

Comment: @dandavis: interesting. Unfortunately there is no residue on it. Just a little rust here and there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tool is used for spreading tile adhesive (or a mortar base).  The large teeth are  for  floor  tile and the  small  teeth are  for  wall  tile.  If kept clean, it will  last a  lifetime!